# A single or two different dimensions

Tags: data-warehouse, dimension

The customers we are dealing with can be corporate or retail. These two types have some fields in common and others (a lot more) different. When designing the data warehouse should we go with a single customer dimension or a corporate customer dimension and a retail customer dimension.

What are the pros and cons of every method ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not advocate for a separate corp_customer and retail_customer dimensions, primarily because your reporting team will be forever having to deal with the common fields with `case when corp_name is null then retail_name else corp_name end` type statements.

Depending on exactly how many 'a lot more' is, id go with a single customer dimension with possibly a lot of null fields -or- a customer_dim that contain all the shared fields and separate customer_retail_dim and customer_corporate_dim tables accessed via [corporate_customer_sk] and [retail_customer_sk] from customer_dim (with appropriate -1 records for both).